# Query to find all the tables with date columns in it

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, date, types

Can anybody let me know the query to find all the tables that has a  date columns on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

This should do the trick, just add in additional types if you need them:

```
select
    so.name table_name
   ,sc.name column_name
   ,st.name data_type
from sysobjects so
inner join syscolumns sc on (so.id = sc.id)
inner join systypes st on (st.type = sc.type)
where so.type = 'U'
and st.name IN ('DATETIME', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'SMALLDATETIME')
```

***edit:*** this also works in Sybase and any other T-SQL variants.

Comment: Easily modified to find all tables with a specific column name as well. (Which is how I got here.)  Thanks!

Comment: Great thanks! For SQL 2008, you would want to update your WHERE clause to read **AND st.name IN ('DATETIME', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'DATETIME2', 'SMALLDATETIME', 'DATETIMEOFFSET')**

Comment: Oops, turns out that sysobject etc were replaced in SQL 2005 with sys.object, sys.columns, etc. I found the query above to be **completely unreliable** in SQL 2008. @RobS answer below provides the correct results (updated to include the full spectrum of types).

Comment: @dividus - when you say "unreliable" what do you mean? Can't you just replace the `sysobjects` with `sys.objects`?

Comment: Is there any way to alter this SQL to show the date fieldnames when they are before a certain date?

Comment: @AntonHughes not in a single query I don't think - you'd need to start with a list of tables and columns that you're interested in and then use execute immediate to find out if any of the data in the table and column in question satisfies your requirements

Comment: in SQL 2014 at least, this list doesn't include columns that are allow nulls.

Comment: had to change this `join systypes st on (st.xtype = sc.xtype)` to fix smalldatetime in sql2016

Answer (score 18):

This uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA on tables in the current database.
Tested in SQL Server 2008.

```
    select distinct c.TABLE_NAME     
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
    where c.DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
```

Another query for SQL 2005/2008 using system views:

```
select tbl.name as 'Table', c.name as 'Column Name', t.name as 'Type'
from sys.columns as c
inner join sys.tables as tbl
on tbl.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types as t
on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
where t.name in ('datetime', 'date')
order by tbl.name
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is another play off of RobS's answer that will get all the different types of date formats and time formats since the introduction of date, datetime2, and time that were introduced.

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE '%date%' OR DATA_TYPE LIKE '%time%'
```

Tested in SQL Server 2012 and 2014 but should work in 2003, 2005, 2008 and many ODBC connections as well.

Answer (score 2):

Slight improvement to RobS query above. This one returns schema name column as well.

```
select s.name as 'SchemaName',
tbl.name as 'Table', c.name as 'Column Name', t.name as 'Type'
from sys.columns as c
inner join sys.tables as tbl
on tbl.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types as t
on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
inner join sys.schemas s
on  tbl.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.name in ('datetime', 'date')
order by s.name, tbl.name
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is Tested Code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
DATA_TYPE='datetime'
```

### **For Multiple datatype you can use Below code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
DATA_TYPE IN ('datatype1','datatype2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I found it searching for similar problem solution.
This what I'm using:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(col.OBJECT_ID) AS [TableName]
FROM
    sys.all_columns col
    INNER JOIN sys.types typ
    ON col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
WHERE
    col.user_type_id IN (61)
```

You can find all basic datatypes here: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/06/find-all-columns-with-varchar-and.html

If You want to find all columns with specific type in a specific table just use this:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(col.OBJECT_ID) AS [TableName]
    ,col.[name] AS [ColName]
    ,typ.[name] AS [TypeName]
FROM
     sys.all_columns col
     INNER JOIN sys.types typ
     ON col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
WHERE
    col.user_type_id IN (61)
    AND
    OBJECT_NAME(col.OBJECT_ID) = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Mayby someone will find it usefull :)